# Assigning value to a string type while declaring it , using if-else control flow in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I'm learning Swift through swift [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/controlflow). While learning about control flow statements, in the if-else part statement I used this code while was given in documentation but it is giving an error saying this syntax is wrong.

```
let temperatureInCelsius = 25

let weatherAdvice = if temperatureInCelsius <= 0 {
    "It's very cold. Consider wearing a scarf."
} else if temperatureInCelsius >= 30 {
    "It's really warm. Don't forget to wear sunscreen."
} else {
    "It's not that cold. Wear a T-shirt."
}
print(weatherAdvice)
```

Errors:

[image]

And in the documentation after this code one more code is given which is giving same errors plus one more error "nil' requires a contextual type"

```
let weatherAdvice = if temperatureInCelsius <= 0 {
    "It's very cold. Consider wearing a scarf."
} else if temperatureInCelsius >= 30 {
    "It's really warm. Don't forget to wear sunscreen."
} else {
    "It's not that cold. Wear a T-shirt."
}


print(weatherAdvice)
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with `if/else` but with how you initialise the property. Maybe skip ahead and read the chapters Properties and Initialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [feature of Swift 5.9](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0380-if-switch-expressions.md), you need the latest Swift 5.9 toolchain installed in Xcode 14, or Xcode 15 beta.

Otherwise do it the traditional way

```
let temperatureInCelsius = 25
let weatherAdvice: String

if temperatureInCelsius <= 0 {
    weatherAdvice = "It's very cold. Consider wearing a scarf."
} else if temperatureInCelsius >= 30 {
    weatherAdvice = "It's really warm. Don't forget to wear sunscreen."
} else {
    weatherAdvice = "It's not that cold. Wear a T-shirt."
}


print(weatherAdvice)
// Prints "It's not that cold. Wear a T-shirt."
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know about this language extension in Swift 5.9 (voted)

Comment: The `let x = if` variant seems ugly and counter-intuitive, but might still be a useful shorthand. The `let x = switch { case: value, case: value, case: value }` variant seems much neater and easier to follow.